# How to get versionCode from package name of any installed app?

Tags: android

I am creating an app like play store for my company. I have upload apk on my server from my web application. I have downloaded apk from url in my android app and prompt to install screen. Now what I want that I am getting new version code and package name from API. I want to get version code of installed app from package name. How can I get version code from package name which I get from API ?

Answer (score 2):

All the provided answers are correct. However, be aware that `PackageInfo.versionCode` has been deprecated in API Level 28. Use `getLongVersionCode` instead for devices running Android Pie or later as below...

```
    var info: PackageInfo? = null
    var versionCode: Long? = null

    try {
        info = context?.packageManager?.getPackageInfo(context?.packageName, 0)
        versionCode =
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.P)  info?.versionCode?.toLong()
        else info?.longVersionCode 
    }
    catch(e: PackageManager.NameNotFoundException){

    }
```

Comment: Better to use PackageInfoCompat

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
public Long getVersionNo(String packageName){
    PackageInfo packageInfo  = null;
    try {
        packageInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(packageName, 0);
        return packageInfo.getLongVersionCode();
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   return null;
}
```

pass package name to this function and it will return the version number of the app installed on device . If app is not found it will return null .

Comment: It is givig error "cannot resolve method getLongVersionCode()"

Comment: make sure you have following imports

`import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;`

Answer (score 0):

```
List<PackageInfo> packagesInstalledList = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
PackageInfo packageInfo = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo( "com.xyz", 0 );

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P){
    long versionCode = PackageInfoCompat.getLongVersionCode(packageInfo);
}else {
    long versionCode = packageInfo.versionCode;//PackageInfo Deprecated in API-28
}

String versionName = packageInfo.versionName;
```

Comment: Pls consider that packageInfo.versionCode was deprecated in API level 28.

Comment: It is givig error "cannot resolve method getLongVersionCode()"

Comment: make sure your targetSdkVersion is 28